# Suggestions for edittext in Samsung S9 Android 8.0 doesn't disable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am using a **editext** in my application for entering details from users. I have disabled the auto-suggestion for **editext** in application and it is working fine for almost all devices, but for Samsung S9 with Android 8.0, it is not working. I have searched and used almost all the solutions available, but can't get relevant solution for it. Samsung S9 is using **Smart Typing** feature for this functionality therefore I think solutions are not working. 
Solutions I have used till now are :-

**Solution 1:**

```
txtField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
txtField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);
```

**Solution 3:**

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txt_field"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxLines="5"
android:background="@drawable/chat_edit_text_bg"
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Above works for other devices, but fails in Samsung devices with Android 8 where **Samsung Smart Typing** is available.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If yes, please share.

Comment: Not found yet mate

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

Add this in your EditText field. This works like a charm and will disable all suggestions when typing on the android keypad.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this combination of `inputType` flags:

```
android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textFilter|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```